# Modal custom sheet not closing

Tags: cocoa, modal-dialog

I am trying to display a custom modal dialogue box and doing it the following way:

EncPasswordSheet is of IBOutlet NSWindow * type.

```
@implementation EncryptionPasswordSheet
-(id)init    
{    
    return self;    
}

- (void)showCustomDlg:(NSWindow *)window
{    
    if (!EncPasswordSheet)    
    {           
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"EncryptionPasswordDlg" owner: self];
    }           
    [NSApp beginSheet:EncPasswordSheet modalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];    
    [NSApp runModalForWindow: EncPasswordSheet];        
    [NSApp endSheet: EncPasswordSheet];    
    [EncPasswordSheet orderOut: self];      
}

- (IBAction)getPasswordFromSheet:(id)sender
{
    password = [passwordField stringValue];
    [NSApp stopModal];    
}

- (IBAction)cancelEncPasswordSheet:(id)sender    
{       
    password = nil;    
    [NSApp stopModal];        
}

@end
```

The dialogue box is being displayed, and takes input. On pressing "ok" or "cancel," the respective IBAction methods are being executed and the program continues.  The problem is that the dialogue box is not getting out of the way - i.e its not getting closed or disappearing.

Comment: You might want to reformat your code to make it a bit easier to understand. Indent with four spaces to format some text as code.

Answer (score 4):

Have you unchecked "Visible At Launch" in Interface Builder for the dialog window? Because if I don't, then the dialog doesn't apppear as a sheet, and doesn't close when done. Try that with your original code.

Comment: yeh tried that trick but didnt work either. Anyways thanks for the reply.

Comment: That's strange because because I made a test project and got it working. Does your dialog actually appear as a sheet sliding down from the main window? How do you call showCustomDlg:? What window do you pass it?

Comment: I just stumbled across this answer and it saved my life. I spent 2 days trying to figure out why my modal dialog sheet was not opening like a sheet but a window... Stupid "visible at launch" +1 for you good sir!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `endSheet` from the IBActions called by your OK and Cancel buttons, which I assume are `getPasswordFromSheet` and `cancelEncPasswordSheet`:

```
- (void)showCustomDlg:(NSWindow *)window {
    if (!EncPasswordSheet) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed: @"EncryptionPasswordDlg" owner: self];
    }

    [NSApp beginSheet:EncPasswordSheet
      modalForWindow:window modalDelegate:nil
      didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
}

- (IBAction)getPasswordFromSheet:(id)sender {
    password = [passwordField stringValue];
    [EncPasswordSheet orderOut: self];
    [NSApp endSheet: EncPasswordSheet];
}

- (IBAction)cancelEncPasswordSheet:(id)sender {
    password = nil;
    [EncPasswordSheet orderOut: self];
    [NSApp endSheet: EncPasswordSheet];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Olbaum for the reply. I tried your method but it did not work out. the problem is i have to use "runModelForWindow" so as to stop the program execution until the user gives an input and presses ok or cancel.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Please ignore this answer and see my new one.